# calling the method into matrix yields 0 instead of correct temps

Tags: java, matrix, methods, 2d

Here's my new part of code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            double tempVal = inputFile.nextDouble();
           degreeMatrix[i][j] = converter(tempVal);

            System.out.println(degreeMatrix[i][j]);
```

ok so I created a file called, inMatrix.txt.  Inside this file say i have a 4 number which is temp in Fahrenheit such as:
12
11
40
19

Now, i want to read these numbers in from the file, and then use a method called converter to convert each number to Celcius.  Then put each new temperature in a 2x2 matrix called degreeMatrix, which I will fill row wise.  and then after processing each number, a for loop will be used to print out each new temperature from degreeMatrix.

Here's my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;


public class TempConversion {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    File matrixFile = new File("inMatrix.txt");
    Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(matrixFile);
    double [][] degreeMatrix = new double[2][2];




    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            double tempVal = inputFile.nextInt();


            System.out.println(degreeMatrix[i][j]);



        //System.out.println(degreeMatrix); 
    }

    }
}

public static double converter(double temp2){

    double tempC = 0.0;

    tempC = (temp2-32.0)*(5.0/9.0);

    System.out.println(tempC);

    return tempC;

   }
}
```

but when i print, it prints everything in zeros. I must be missing a line of code in main right before:

```
System.out.println(degreeMatrix[i][j]);
```

but cant figure out whats missing. thanks for you help.

Comment: ok so you want us to complete your homework. This way will not work. Go and learn java

Comment: no, i'm asking why is it printing 0 instead of the number in matrix. if you noticed i have done all the coding myself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not putting anything in the matrix, which is why it prints 0. 
You can insert the converted value in your matrix as follows:

```
int tempVal = inputFile.nextInt();
degreeMatrix[i][j] = converter(tempInDegrees);
```

Note that method names should start with a lower case in Java.

Comment: Thank U. It's always the smallest things that gives the biggest headaches. just had to fix that and a few small errors with int and double and everything working just fine.

Answer (score 1):

The line of code you are missing is this:

```
    degreeMatrix[i][j] = tempVal;
```

You have read the value from file into `tempVal`, which is fine, but you didn't store it in your matrix before you printed the value :)